# Javascript getting result in 2 different functions and Adding them together

Tags: javascript, html

I got this 2 different javascript Functions sum and diff and they have 2 result. the problem is that how can i get the result of the 2 function and add them and display it on the other textbox.

```
function sum() {

      var basicpay = document.getElementById('basicpay').value;
      var overtime = document.getElementById('overtime').value;
      var regularholiday = document.getElementById('regularholiday').value;
      var specialholiday = document.getElementById('specialholiday').value;
      var allowanceday = document.getElementById('allowanceday').value;
      var others1 = document.getElementById('others1').value;
      var grosspay = document.getElementById('grosspay').value;
      var monthpay13 = document.getElementById('monthpay13').value;

        var result = 

        parseInt(basicpay) + 
        parseInt(overtime) +
        parseInt(regularholiday) +
        parseInt(specialholiday) +
        parseInt(allowanceday) +
        parseInt(others1) +
        parseInt(grosspay) +
        parseInt(monthpay13);


        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('totalincome').value = result;
        }
        }
```

The other one function goes here:

```
function diff() {           

        var absent = document.getElementById('absent').value;
        var tardiness = document.getElementById('tardiness').value;
        var sss = document.getElementById('sss').value;
        var pagibig = document.getElementById('pagibig').value;
        var philhealth = document.getElementById('philhealth').value;
        var cashadvances = document.getElementById('cashadvances').value;
        var withholdingtax = document.getElementById('withholdingtax').value;
        var others = document.getElementById('others').value; 

        var result =

        parseInt(absent) - 
        parseInt(tardiness) -
        parseInt(sss) -
        parseInt(pagibig) -
        parseInt(philhealth) -
        parseInt(cashadvances) -
        parseInt(withholdingtax) -
        parseInt(others);


        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('totaldeductions').value = result;

        }
        }
```

i just want to subract the totaldeductions and totalincome and show it to the other textbox. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to the top of your Javascript:

```
function calculate() {
   document.getElementById('both').value = sum() + diff();
}
```

Add a new HTML element to hold your answer:

```
19.<input type="text" Placeholder="Both" id="both" />
```

Change all your onkeyup to this:

```
onkeyup="calculate();"
```

Finally, you need to change your "var result = ..." code, otherwise it works only when ALL numbers have been entered.

I recommend you do less manual work and let your textboxes bind to variables automatically. Do a few of these tutorials and you'll see how easy it is: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

Comment: what do you mean sir *you need to change your "var result = ..." code,* what should i change there?

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the function, you can do it like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('othertextbox').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('totalincome').value) - parseInt(document.getElementById('totaldeductions').value);
}
```

(Add the above code to your Javascript)

Comment: where should i put this and how can i display it sir?